# Is it feasible to recover a zip file password consisting of about 16 digits?

Tags: passwords, brute-force, zip

A friend of mine lost the password of a zip file of her. She remembers that the password contains digits only (that is, only 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9) and is 16 characters long or so. The digits in the password were chosen randomly, by randomly hitting keys. She kept her password in a TXT file, but the file is gone.

Is there any feasible way to recover the password? If so, how can we do that?

I read on the Internet that such long passwords can't be recovered, but I think our case is special because we know that the password is digit-only. We are laywomen in mathematics and can't estimate the amount of time needed to crack the password in our case. Should my friend simply let it go, or is it worth spending time and effort trying to recover the password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the password were chosen randomly, by randomly hitting keys

**TL;DR**: [***Feasible***](https://mobile.twitter.com/hashcat/status/1129441728761610242) to crack if the archive was protected with *ZipCrypto*, ***not feasible*** if the archive was protected with *"WinZip" AES encryption*.

---

16 of random digits = 10^16 = **10 000 000 000 000 000** of combinations = **53 bits**

It means that, for instance, if you're able to achieve a password verification speed of **100 000 hashes/sec**, it will take the following amount of time to **brute force** the password:

1. 100000000000 seconds
2. 1666666667 minutes
3. 27777778 hours
4. 1157407 days
5. **3171 years**

More things to consider *(thank you, comment section!*):

1. **1000 000 hashes/sec** => **317 years** of brute force
2. **10 000 000 hashes/sec** => **32 years** of brute force ([depending on particular WinZip/7-Zip/PKZIP algorithm using GPU (see benchmarks for Nvidia RTX 2080)](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/47098d25f171ec1808b519615be1b90d)).
3. **30 GH/sec** => **4 days** (I can see some `hashcat` measurements about PKZIP in the [same benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/47098d25f171ec1808b519615be1b90d))
4. *22.7 ZettaHash/sec* => **a second** of brute force. Seems like that is feasible for *original PKZIP encryption algorithm* which could be brute forced using some *specific attack* with the speed of ["22.7 ZettaHash/sec on a single RTX 2080Ti"](https://mobile.twitter.com/hashcat/status/1129441728761610242). You can crack 16 numbers in **seconds** then. *Not AES+PBKDF2* yet which is used in WinZip.

At least two different algorithms are widely used to protect zip archive:

1. ***ZipCrypto*** (PKZIP encryption)

   - Original PKZIP encryption is absolutely [weak](http://math.ucr.edu/~mike/zipattacks.pdf) (it uses CRC32-based key derivation): from 10 MH/sec to [30-100 GH/sec](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/47098d25f171ec1808b519615be1b90d) and up to [22.7 ZettaHash/s on 1GPU](https://mobile.twitter.com/hashcat/status/1129441728761610242). You can crack 16 numbers from **seconds** to 1-2 days feasibility depending on specific attack, hardware and optimization set. If you're not lucky enough than it would be years still.
2. ***AES encryption*** ([WnZip encryption](http://kb.winzip.com/help/help_encryption.htm))

   - WinZip uses AES-based encryption with PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA1 1000 iterations key derivation: [5 MegaHash/s on 1GPU](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/47098d25f171ec1808b519615be1b90d). And this is **32 years**.

Comment: What verification speed can be achieved on a normal computer?

Comment: As I remember on my 8-core computer with GPU enabled I had kind of ~80 000 hashes/sec using `hashcat`, but maybe somebody has better configuration, that's why I assumed higher rate. But even with 1000 000 hashes per second you end up with 317 years of brute force.

Comment: But with some sort of supercomputer it would be definitely feasible :) E.g. it could take a couple of weeks

Comment: Or, just a re-purposed bitcoin miner.  You can get a used Antminer S9 for ~$200 (https://www.ebay.com/itm/164120326103) which can do 14 terra-hashes per second.  At that rate, it would take about 8 days to brute force 10^16 hashes.

Comment: This answer could be improved by taking [the known cryptographic weaknesses in the ZIPCrypto algorithm into account](http://math.ucr.edu/~mike/zipattacks.pdf).

Comment: @mti2935, you can reprogram FGPA-based miners, but you can't repurpose ASIC-based miners for different math from the math they were engineered for. It would have to be a ZIP-specific ASIC.

Comment: Worse, the password wasn't 16 characters long, it was "... 16 characters long or so." Could have been less than 16, which isn't too bad, but what if it was 17 characters? 18?

Comment: Also depends on ZIP variant. To support the math, here's benchmarks from the latest hashcat beta (pre-6.0, May 2020) for PKZIP and WinZip on six GTX 1080s:
11600 - 7-Zip (Iterations: 16384): 1876.2 kH/s; 
17200 - PKZIP (Compressed): 10885.4 MH/s; 
17220 - PKZIP (Compressed Multi-File): 22151.8 MH/s; 
17225 - PKZIP (Mixed Multi-File): 26543.5 MH/s; 
17230 - PKZIP (Mixed Multi-File Checksum-Only): 40209.9 MH/s; 
17210 - PKZIP (Uncompressed): 6367.2 MH/s; 
13600 - WinZip (Iterations: 999): 20579.6 kH/s;

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Do you have a link to the research so I could improve my answer?

Comment: Here's a public test from a domain expert: https://gist.github.com/epixoip/23068f4bc81db505115c43e7751522f2

Comment: @RoyceWilliams I found the original link you used: https://gist.github.com/epixoip/47098d25f171ec1808b519615be1b90d. Either way, thank you! And I improved my answer thanks to comment section

Comment: Great! (And for the record, I didn't use a link the first time - I did those benchmarks on my own system. :) Linking much better, of course!)

Comment: @RoyceWilliams and Mitsuko. Upgraded the answer. I found the result of 22 ZettaHashes/sec for ZipCrypto on `hashcat`, and it means just a second to crack 16 digits. BUT! There are 2 options: ZipCrypto and WinZip's AES-based encryption. So shortly, it is feasible to crack original ZipCrypto encryption, and not feasible AES-based WinZip encryption. So need to know encryption algorithm. Anyways, see upgraded answer.

Comment: That's only for a very specific attack type that may not be applicable to a given zipfile.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams Yeah, sure. Basically, benchmarks usually lack of details, so I just assume that it is kind of feasible to some extent. But yes. P.S.: I will add softer wording

Answer (score 1):

16 characters is quite long. Even with numbers only it will take a long time. I'm not sure how plausible it will be to try and brute force. Perhaps consider using a file recovery program to try and recover her password txt file instead. If you wish to try brute forcing the zip archive here's a php script for doing so.

Script:

```
<?php
#This script will try all numeric passwords which are 16 characters long (excluding those which start with zeros), and reveal the password on completion.
#Install PHP 7, and p7zip (eg: "sudo apt-get install php p7zip-full"). '/dev/null' must exist! Save this script as "script.php" in $PWD. Copy zip archive to $PWD, and name it "file.zip". Execute this script in terminal (eg: "php script.php").
$i = 999999999999999;
while ($i <= 9999999999999999){
    echo "Trying {$i}\n";
    $output = shell_exec("7z t file.zip -p{$i} 2>&1 > /dev/null && echo $?");
    $output = trim($output);
    if ($output === '0'){
        echo "Password is {$i}\n";
        $i = 9999999999999999;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Sample Output (trimmed for size):

```
user1@vm1:~/Music$ php script.php
Trying 9999999999999995
Trying 9999999999999996
Trying 9999999999999997
Trying 9999999999999998
Trying 9999999999999999
Password is 9999999999999999
user1@vm1:~/Music$
```

Comment: You can't copyright submissions on this site. Please refer to ***this site's*** copyright: "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa. rev 2020.5.21.36879"